# Identify process done using SSH

Tags: ssh

I connect remotely using SSH (Putty) to RPI, having UBUNTU 16.04 installed, to run a python file to control GPIO switches.

I wish to identify ( and log ) if that py file was executed by local user on RPI or by remote SSH user ( that logs on with same Usename ).

Using : `who`, or `w` at UBUNTU's command line shows user connected via pts and its IP... but it is not enough to know.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an SSH session when `SSH_CLIENT`, `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`, `SSH_CONNECTION` and/or SSH_TTY is defined. If you want to make it work across `su` commands add them to `env_keep` in `sudoers`.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9605/how-can-i-detect-if-the-shell-is-controlled-from-ssh/9607#9607 for more methods.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: More about what? Those are BASH variables. And you can use those in python to create a if statement.